# Does dolphindb support regular expression like the re in python?

Tags: python, dolphindb

I would like to ask, is there a function dolphindb, which can replace functions such as numbers in strings

Comment: https://www.dolphindb.cn/en/help/index.html?regexReplace.html

Comment: Thirty seconds of searching will find you results in the dolphindb documentation, for example https://www.dolphindb.com/help/DataManipulation/StringObjects/index.html - please search __first__ before asking a question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not tech support. If you want to know whether a library has some particular functionality, the correct places to look are the documentation and a search engine.

Comment: `re` isn't a function, it's a regular expression library. Googling "dolphindb regular expression" is the way to research this.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in DolphinDB use UTF-8 character encoding. The following functions support the use of regular expressions: regexFind, regexReplace, regexCount.

For more details, please refer to the User Manual: https://www.dolphindb.com/help/DataManipulation/StringObjects/index.html